# Как сделать Каптчу на golang?

Tags: golang, captcha

Подскажите пакет или как сделать Каптчу на  golang ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На гитхабе целая [куча](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=captcha%20language%3AGo&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=&l=Go) имплементаций данного сервиса на любой вкус.

Comment: та да- но я примера так и не нашёл- что б закопипастить и оно работало

Comment: да взять хотя бы первую из списка, там же в документации все расписано как юзать :\

Comment: спасибо. протупил- не увидел примеров